# Error passing 2D char* array into a function

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, char

I'm trying to pass a 2D array of char* into a function. I am getting this error:

```
"cannot convert 'char* (*)[2]' to 'char***' for argument '1' to 'int foo(char***)'"
```

Code:

```
int foo(char*** hi)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    char* bar[10][10];
    return foo(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array is an array of `10` `char*` arrays, each storing `10` `char*` pointers.

This means that when passing it to a function whose parameter is not a reference, it is converted to a `pointer to an array of 10 char*`. The correct function parameter type is thus

```
int foo(char* (*hi)[10])
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    char* bar[10][10];
    return foo(bar);
}
```

Read further on this [Pet peeve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/484900#484900) entry on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of your array is not going to change, you're better off using references to the array in your function. Its safer and cleaner. For example:

```
int foo(char* (&hi)[10][10] )
{
 int return_val = 0;
 //do something
 //hi[5][5] = 0;
 return return_val;
}

int main()
{
    char* bar[10][10];
    return foo(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a bad time to introduce the concept of references?

Off hand, I would say that an extra '&' would be needed on the calling side. That being said, this is a dangerous game to play.

Why are you allocating this? Why is it on the stack? Why are you typing it to a char*** in the receiving function?

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int foo(char* hi[10][10])
{
}

int main()
{
    char* bar[10][10];
    return foo(bar);
}
```

Alternatively, use a reference, a vector of vectors or boost::multi_array.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use static array sizes for foo.

Comment: @CookieOfFortune, Note that the first "10" is not respected by the compiler. The parameter has the same type as in my answer.